# Integer sequence, possible closed form solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

I was redirected to ask on Math.SE if there may be a closed form solution to find values in this sequence.

Original question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201631/integer-sequence-and-ram-limits

I am trying to calculate the set of unique differences in a sequence, however the sequence grows fast and I hit the RAM limit of my PC for nthPrimeToUse = 11. For nthPrimeToUse 1 to 10 the output of Length[abc4] is: 0,1,2,3,5,7,10,13,16,20,... I am trying to find at least a few more terms if possible.

Here is the Mathematica code:
Updated code: (outputs: 0,1,2,3,5,7,10,13,16,20 for nthPrimeToUse=1 to 10)

```
nthPrimeToUse = 5; 
primeNumber = Prime[nthPrimeToUse];
Primorial[n_] := Times @@ Prime[Range[n]]
PrimorialToUse = Primorial[nthPrimeToUse - 1];
range = PrimorialToUse*primeNumber*2;
x = Select[(primeNumber) Range@range, GCD[#, PrimorialToUse ] == 1 &];
x = x/primeNumber;
valuesDivisibleByPrime = {}
For[i = 0, i < Length[x], i++,
 If[GCD[x[[i]], primeNumber] != 1,
  AppendTo[valuesDivisibleByPrime, x[[i]]]
  ]
 ]
x = Differences[valuesDivisibleByPrime] ;
CountDistinct[x]
```

This code is faster, possibly equivalent to the above code for nthPrimeToUse > 3 (outputs: 0,0,1,3,5,7,10,13,16,20 for nthPrimeToUse=1 to 10)

```
nthPrimeToUse = 5;
primeNumber = Prime[nthPrimeToUse];
Primorial[n_] := Times @@ Prime[Range[n]]
PrimorialToUse = Primorial[nthPrimeToUse - 1];

coprimesOfPrimorial = 
Select[Range[1, PrimorialToUse], CoprimeQ[PrimorialToUse, #] &];
abc1 = Length[coprimesOfPrimorial];
abc2 = Differences[coprimesOfPrimorial];
abc3 = CountDistinct[abc2];
abc4 = DeleteDuplicates[abc2];
abc4 = abc4*primeNumber;
Sort[abc4]
Length[abc4]
```

Thanks.

cheers,
Jamie

Comment: A closed form is rather unlikely to exist.

Comment: can you describe your sequence in plain English?

Comment: For a Primorial interval x, ie 2*3*5*7=210, take the numbers y < x which are coprime to x, giving the 48 values = 1,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,121,127,131,137,139,143,149,151,157,163,167,169,173,179,181,187,191,193,197,199,209.  The distinct differences in this list (Mathematica DeleteDuplicates[Differences[y]]) gives 5 values, which is the fifth value in the sequence.  The sixth value in the sequence uses coprimes of 2*3*5*7*11 etc.

Comment: How is the value for $2*3 = 6$ equal to $2$? I get only $1$ value, as the values for $y$ are $1, 5$. This makes $1$ distinct value for the differences.

Comment: Hi, 0,0,1,3,5,7,10,13,16,20 is the correct sequence for that algorithm, which is the second Mathematica program.  I wasn't aware the first three terms don't match, so there are actually two sequences.